# JSON Decoder в swift 4 не работает

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Добрый день! Пытаюсь скормить Свифту JSON и спарсить его, используя новый JSONDecoder, т.е. без сторонних библиотек.

Вот структура протокола Decodable:

```
struct Track: Decodable {
    var aWaypoints: [Any]?
    var aTrack: [String:Any]?
    var aPoints: [TrackPoint]?
    var sMsg: String?
    var sMsgTitle: String?
    var bOptimizePath: Bool?
    var aWeather: [String:Any]?
    var aPhotos: String?
    var aCardioData: [Any]?
    var bStateError: Bool?
    var min_id: String?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    }
}

struct TrackPoint {
    var point = [61.784128, 34.36778, 51.7, 1470833497, 0, 0, 1]
}
```

А вот код вызова URL Session во ViewController

```
class GraphViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var idValue: UILabel!

    var temp = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        idValue.text = temp
        let jsonurlstring = "http://avionicus.com/android/track_v0649.php?avkey=1M1TE9oeWTDK6gFME9JYWXqpAGc%3D&hash=58ecdea2a91f32aa4c9a1d2ea010adcf2348166a04&track_id=\(idValue.text ?? "")&user_id=22)"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonurlstring) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard err == nil else { return }

            print(data)

            do {
                let tracks = try JSONDecoder().decode(Track.self, from: data)
                print(tracks)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Error:", error)
            }
        }.resume()
        }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я не прав, почему автоматом не подцепляются ключи из JSON? Пример JSON по [ссылке](http://avionicus.com/android/track_v0649.php?avkey=1M1TE9oeWTDK6gFME9JYWXqpAGc%3D&hash=58ecdea2a91f32aa4c9a1d2ea010adcf2348166a04&track_id=36131&user_id=22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему где-то в структуре была опечатка или еще что-то, я так и не понял.

Работает следующий код:

Структура:

import Foundation

```
struct Track: Decodable {
    var aWaypoints = [String]()
    var aTrack: ATrack?
    var aPoints: [[Double]]?
    var sMsg: String?
    var sMsgTitle: String?
    var bStateError: Bool?
    var min_id: String?
}

struct ATrack: Decodable {
    var type: String?
    var dt_start: String?
    var dt_end: String?
    var time: String?
    var distance: String?
    var id_track: String?
    var sp_avg: String?
    var sp_max: String?
    var calories: String?
    var description: String?
    var access: String?
    var weight: String?
    var cardio: String?
    var hr_max: Double?
    var hr_avg: Double?
    var var_max: String?
    var var_min: String?
    var status: Bool?
}
```

Вызов и парсинг JSON

```
class GraphViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var idValue: UILabel!

    var temp = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        idValue.text = temp
        let jsonUrlString = "http://avionicus.com/android/track_v0649.php?avkey=1M1TE9oeWTDK6gFME9JYWXqpAGc%3D&hash=58ecdea2a91f32aa4c9a1d2ea010adcf2348166a04&track_id=\(idValue.text!)&user_id=22)"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard err == nil else { return }
            print(data)

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let track = try decoder.decode(Track.self, from: data)
                print(track.aPoints)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Error:", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Данный код успешно печатает массив массивов aPoints